# The style object and HTML attibute

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, browser

Can someone explain what the `style` object is? Is it an HTML DOM Property or a JavaScript Object? And how does it relate to:

- HTML
- CSS
- DOM
- JavaScript

And then can you do the same thing for the inline HTML `style` attribute, but also tell me how this attribute compares to an event attribute like `onclick`. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `.style` accesses the element *Style* (JS is supposed to do that :) an element style object has a collection all the element's styles retrieved by the browser.  `onclick` is a method that attaches the click handler to an element. Otherwise the question is pretty vague.

Comment: Asking what “the `style` object” is postulates that there is such an object, but you are not defining what that means. In effect, you are asking for a lecture on a very vaguely described topic, rather than presenting a practical problem that you are facing.

Comment: Here is a link to what I was looking at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535870(v=vs.85).aspx and I'm still a little unclear as to what the style object is. That is, on a low level, like does the browser view this code `<p onclick="this.style.cssText = 'color:red;'">Hi</p>` specifically `this.style.cssText` as JavaScript code? Does it have to send the `onclick` value to the JavaScript interpreter? Because I thought the browser had to see the `<script>` tag to invoke the JavaScript interpreter. Sorry for being a little vague, but I was hoping for some details like @Mark is sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example,

```
<span id="myspan" style="color:red">some red text</span>
```

`style` is an **HTML** attribute. Its value contains **CSS**. You can access it via **JavaScript** by first retrieving the HtmlElement object,

```
var myspan = document.getElementById('myspan');
```

And then accessing its `style` **property**,

```
myspan.style
```

Which is a JavaScript object, which has its own set of properties, such as `color`.

The "DOM" is essentially the name given to HTML once it has been processed into a tree-like structure by your browser. It can be rendered to your screen, or manipulated via JavaScript. "HTML" is essentially just text until your browser does something with it.

Comment: It might be `style` property of an element node that the question is about – after all, its value is an object. But then the question is what the object contains – and it contains equivalents of CSS properties *as set in a `style` attribute*. So if there is a rule e.g. in an external style sheet that sets a property on the element, this is *not* reflected in the `style` property.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Mark! I'm still curious about how the browser handles this code: `<p onclick="this.style.cssText = 'color:red;'">Hi</p>` specifically `this.style.cssText = 'color:red;'` Does the browser treat this as JavaScript code? Does it have to send the `onclick` value to the JavaScript interpreter? Because I thought the browser had to see the `<script>` tag to invoke the JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: @Dusty: Just as the `style` tag contains CSS, the `onclick` and [many other](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) attributes contain JavaScript. Any code inside of those attributes is ran through the JS interpreter; no `<script>` tag necessary. Furthermore, you can even run JS inside of an href via `<a href="javascript:alert('hello!')"/>`

Comment: Thanks @Mark!! You're the reason why I love this site!

Answer (score 2):

If an **HTML** element contains inline `style` attribute with style declarations, for example

```html
<div style="color:red; background-color:white;" id="example"> example text </div>
```

then these inline declarations will be stored in **DOM** in element's `style` object as element's properties:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('example');
alert(element.style.color + element.style.backgroundColor); // 'red white'
```

This `element.style` object is useful for easy adjusting element's styles.

[Quote from Mozilla's website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.style): "the style property has the same (and highest) priority in the CSS cascade as an inline style declaration via the style attribute, it is useful for setting style on one specific element." This means: if browser have to choose between multiple declared styles the one that should be applied to an element, then [inline style has higher priority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Crescent_order_of_specificity) than other selectors, e.g.

```css
#example { color:blue; }
```

```html
<div id="example" style="color:red;"> example text </div>
```

and so in this case the red color is applied to the element.

So in most cases changing `element.style.propertyName` also changes element's appearance on the page. The only exception i know of, is `!important` overridance rule. For example:

```css
#example { color:blue !important; } /* force color to blue */
```

```html
<div style="color:red;" id="example"> example text </div>
```

```js
alert(element.style.color); // alerts 'red', even though the text is forced to blue

alert(window.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue('color')); // alerts 'rgb(0,0,255)' ~ blue
```

(The above is also the reason why it's recommended to use the `!important` modifier very carefully and sparingly.)

To answer the rest of your question: the DOM's onclick property (or HTML's onclick attribute) is a legacy from older browsers, but it's still very useful in many cases where you need to attach only single event handler. For attaching multiple event handlers we can use addEventListener DOM method. [Simple test here](http://jsfiddle.net/RvBFH/).

Answer (score 1):

Consider this HTML tag:

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
```

You can access this element in JavaScript:

```
var search = document.getElementById('search');
```

Now, you have a variable called `search` and it is an object:

```
typeof search;
// object

alert(search.constructor.name);
// HTMLInputElement
```

The `style` attribute is available for such elements.
It is an object:

```
search.style;
// CSSStyleDeclaration {parentRule: null, length: 0, cssText: "", alignmentBaseline: "", background: ""…}
```

And whenever you change a property of it, it will affect your DOM in browser:

```
search.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Now your textbox will be red in the browser.

- You can check the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aGH3x/).